# 95% CI of R^2 in a linear mixed weighted regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to calculate the R^2 and its 95%CI in linear mixed weighted regression. Since the summary of *lme()* doesn't provide R^2, I am using the *r.squaredGLMM()* from *MuMIn* package, and *boot()* from *boot* package. (If you have better way to do this, please let me know!!!) However, I found the upper and lower bound to be the same number. Why? I am using the mtcars data as an example here:

```
library(lme4)
library(boot)
library(MuMIn)

foo <- boot(mtcars, function(data, indices) 
  r.squaredGLMM(lme(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars, 
                    random= ~1|gear, weights= ~carb))[1], R=1000)
foo$t0
quantile(foo$t,  c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I forgot to add `data=mtcars[indices,]`... I would want to delete the question, but thought maybe it could help someone new with R having the similar question.